# tesseract OCR output words bounds

Tags: command-line, tesseract, words

How to output words bounds using tesseract command line with config file?

So far I been able to output chars using

```
tesseract image.png myBox makebox
```

This created a myBox.box file that looks like this:

```
N 51 1844 75 1874 0
o 80 1843 100 1867 0
S 113 1843 136 1875 0
I 140 1844 145 1874 0
M 151 1844 181 1874 0
c 197 1843 216 1867 0
a 219 1843 238 1867 0
r 243 1844 254 1867 0
d 256 1843 275 1876 0
```

How ever those only chars and I need words, so I been able to combine it with standard output

```
tesseract image.png myBox
```

This creates a file like this:

```
no simcard
```

Combining those two outputs I can get words bounds. How ever I prefer to find a method that does not require examining the same image twice. Please help

Comment: Why don't you parse the first output? There you have the output text and the letter bounds and you don't need the second command.

Comment: How can you tell what are words from the first output? Those can be any chars

Comment: Indeed, you are right, there is no space in the first output. However, a solution for this, which may not be the best, would be to loop through letters and see the distance between them and detect when there is a bigger space or a character on the *next row*.

Comment: @Ibrahim yep, I am doing my best to doge this solution, especially as I know that this tool capable to output words, so they probably already figured this out, so just need to learn how to use it.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman Did you solve this issue?